# TypeScript 1.8 installed in Visual Studio 2013 is missing the tsc.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I've installed TypeScript for Visual Studio 2013 (downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48739)

It's added the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\ **1.8** folder ... but there's no **tsc.exe** file in the folder (although there is a tsc.js).

Without the 1.8 tsc.exe, VS is defaulting to compiling on an earlier version of the tsc.exe (in the \1.6 folder).

How can I get the missing 1.8 tsc.exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall any previous Visual Studio powertools you have on your system and re-install it after successful installation of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2013.